# Starvation occuring in the Dining Philosophers code

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency

Here's my implementation of the Philosopher dinner concurrence problem. I works only for two threads and the rest suffers from starvation, literally ;) I appreciate if you could find the cause of it.

Here's the output:

```
Philosopher 2 is eating
Philosopher 0 is eating
Philosopher 2 is eating
Philosopher 0 is eating
Philosopher 2 is eating
Philosopher 0 is eating
Philosopher 2 is eating
Philosopher 0 is eating
Philosopher 2 is eating
Philosopher 2 is eating
Philosopher 0 is eating
Philosopher 2 is eating
Philosopher 0 is eating
```

Here's the code:

```
public class PhilosophersDinner {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Chopstick2[] chopsticks = new Chopstick2[5];
        Philosopher [] philosophers = new Philosopher[5];

        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            Chopstick2 stick = new Chopstick2();
            chopsticks[i] = stick;
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            Philosopher philo = new Philosopher(chopsticks[i] , chopsticks[(i+1)%5], i+"");
            philosophers[i] = philo;
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < philosophers.length; i++) {
            new Thread(philosophers[i]).start();
        }
    }

}

class Philosopher implements Runnable {

    private final Chopstick2 left;
    private final Chopstick2 right;
    private final String id;

    public Philosopher(Chopstick2 l, Chopstick2 r, String id){
        this.left = l;
        this.right = r;
        this.id = id;
    }

    public void eat(){
        if (left.pickUp()) {
            if (right.pickUp()) {
                chew();
                putDown();
            } else left.putDown();
        }
    }


    public void run(){
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            eat();
        }
    }

    public void chew(){
        try {
            System.out.println("Philosopher "+id+" is eating");
            Thread.sleep(400);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            // release lock here?
        } 
    }

    public void putDown(){
        left.putDown();
        right.putDown();
    }

}

class Chopstick2 {
    private volatile boolean taken = false;

    public synchronized boolean pickUp(){
        if (!taken) { 
            taken = true;
            return true;
        }
        else return false;
    }

    public synchronized void putDown(){
        taken = false;
    }
}
```

Comment: I only looked over the code briefly but the classic solution to this problem is to have at least one right handed philosopher and at least one left handed, this will avoid deadlock.  To avoid starvation classically you would implement a monitor(a semaphore combined with a queue).

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out Jake, but how can it deadlock if the left chopstick is released when the right one is taken?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the first two `Philosophers` to get chopsticks spend half of a second eating and during that time the other three diners try to eat until they give up and quit.

One solution would be to have all of the philosophers eat for a specified amount of time instead of making a specific number of attempts to eat.

```
    for (long i = System.currentTimeMillis()+10000; i > System.currentTimeMillis(); ) {
        eat();
    }
```

Comment: Should be `>`. Better yet, replace this with a decent variable name and a `while` loop.